# Changing the language manually to Simplifies Chinese

Tags: android, chinese-locale

I use this code to change the language of my app manually:

```
Locale locale = new Locale(OneLanguageCode);   
Locale.setDefault(locale);  
Configuration config = new Configuration();  
config.locale = locale;  
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

I set in OneLanguageCode the international code. Everything works find for every code I have tried like "en", "es", "fr" and so on... But I am driving myself crazy with simplified Chinese.
In that case I have the folder called **values-zh-rCN** where the strings are. It works well if I set the device language to Simplified Chinese. But there is no way to set it manually with the code above.
I have tried using "zh-CN" as the OneLanguageCode value, but no success either. It is displayed in English.

As I said all this work with other languages. I can have people with Dutch as their device default language but have French in my app. Why am I not able to have Dutch as the device default language but have traditional Chinese in my app?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help of user2968888 this is how I solved:

```
Locale locale;
if(OneLanguageCode.equals("schinese")) //any tag here to know it is Simplified Chinese
   locale = Locale.SIMPLIFIED_CHINESE;
else
   locale = new Locale(OneLanguageCode);
Locale.setDefault(locale);  
Configuration config = new Configuration();  
config.locale = locale;  
getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Locale locale = new Locale("en_CA"); 
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
context.getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
```

Comment: Which `TranslationHelper` are you referring to?

Comment: Yes I do everything before setContentView. As I said it works for other languages. What do you mean with "TranslationHelper"? Thanks